# AngularJS Provider Multiple Instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, websocket

I would like to ask if there's a possibility to use a provider like angular-websocket library in a module and use it in multiple modules of an angular ng-app.

```
var 1stWebsocket = angular.module('1stWebsocket', [
    "angular-websocket"
]);

1stWebsocket.config(function(WebSocketProvider) {
    WebSocketProvider
        .prefix('')
        .uri('ws://'+SH_WS_CONSTANTS.SERVER_IP+SH_WS_CONSTANTS.CONTROL_PORT)
        .binaryType("arraybuffer");
});

1stWebsocket.service('1stWebsocket', [
    '$rootScope', 'WebSocket', function($rootScope,  WebSocket) {
      //Websocket code
    });


var 2ndWebsocket = angular.module('2ndWebsocket', [
    "angular-websocket"
]);

2ndWebsocket.config(function(WebSocketProvider) {
    WebSocketProvider
        .prefix('')
        .uri('ws://'+SH_WS_CONSTANTS.SERVER_IP+SH_WS_CONSTANTS.CONTROL_PORT)
        .binaryType("arraybuffer");
});

2ndWebsocket.service('2ndWebsocket', [
    '$rootScope', 'WebSocket', function($rootScope,  WebSocket) {
      //Websocket code
    });


  var app = angular.module('myApp', [

    '1stWebsocket',
    '2ndWebsocket'
]);
```

I can only see one websocket instance :(

I need to use the 2 different instances of websockets that connect to different ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS providers, factories and services are singletons.

[How to create (singleton) AngularJS services in 4 different ways](http://blog.jdriven.com/2013/03/how-to-create-singleton-angularjs-services-in-4-different-ways/)

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

You should create a `WebSocketCreator` service, with a `.create` method that returns a new instance each time.